# Process Builder Formula Help

Tags: process-builder

In process builder, I created the formula below to transfer contact information onto the opportunity during opportunity creation from a contact.  If anyone can help me determine why the bold section of my formula doesn't execute or keep evaluating FALSE.  I made sure the contact.Partner_contact__c is equal to TRUE but keeps getting NULL as the input. Is there an issue with my formula?  There is no errors.  Thank you in advance.

Opportunity: Partner Account field:

```
IF(NOT(ISNULL([Opportunity].Primary_Contact__r.New_Partner_Contact__c)) , 
  [Opportunity].Primary_Contact__r.New_Partner_Contact__r.AccountId , 
**IF([Opportunity].Primary_Contact__r.Partner_Contact__c = TRUE,
    [Opportunity].Primary_Contact__r.AccountId** , 
     NULL)
)
```

Comment: so the Opportunity has a lookup to a Contact that in turn has a lookup to another Contact (via `New_Partner_Contact__r`) ?.  Did you check the debug log to understand the values of each of the fields when the PB executes. I'm not convinced that the first true clause isn't executing (and evaluating to null)

Comment: You cannot compare `Partner_Contact__c` to TRUE because it is a lookup field.  You need to use ISBLANK if you want test that a value exists.

Comment: Thank you, both. The data in my org. is a mess.  The first condition using ISNULL or NOT(ISNULL) does return the right value.  The second condition, I'm trying to evaluate if the field Partner_Contact__c is TRUE or not.  This field is a checkbox field. Primary_contact is a lookup.  Thank you, again.